# Texture uv map is not applied to the object while I'm following the projection paiting tutorial

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, uv-image-editor

I don't know what's happened, but after having added a camera and some lamp to the scene, the uv maps that before has been applied correctly to the object, now stopped working. I added an image file on the `texture panel` and it seems that it has been recognized, but it isn't listed on the `material tab`. The result is that the object appears always greyish. I attached a lot of pictures, to show you the configuration in the key areas of blender settings:

1. Here you can see that on the `texture panel` I selected an image texture

[image: 1]

2. Here you can see that on the `material tab` the image texture selected on the point 1. is not available.

[image: 2]

3. Here you can see that in `edit mode`,I see no texture applied to the model

[image: 3]

4. Here you can see that in `object mode`, I see no texture applied to the model

[image: 4]

5. Instead, in the `texture paint mode`, I see the texture applied correctly and you can also see how is the configuration settings under the `slots tab`

[image: 5]

6. Here you can see how is the configuration settings under the `tools tab`

[image: 6]

7. uv image editor pic

[image: 7]

Comment: Can you attach a screen shot of the UV Image Editor? Is the texture linked to your shader?

Comment: refresh the page...i added it as picture 7

Comment: Sorry my bad, I meant to say the Node Editor, the one that shows the your material's nodes and links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by @lemon is correct, here's how to do it using nodes, which I find more intuitive to work with:
1- Open a Node editor window, having your object selected, you should see it's material node setup. If you don't make sure the highlighted buttons in the image below are selected, then press <kbd>Numpad . (period)</kbd>  
[image]
2- While your mouse is over the Node Editor window, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to add a node, choose Texture > Image texture,then drag the yellow dot, which represent the color from the image texture node, to the yellow dot in your shader node.
[image]
 
3- Click Open in the image texture node, and browse/choose your saved texture file.
Using the Node Editor is much easier to mix your shaders and textures to get a more complex material when needed.
That been said, the reason why you couldn't see the texture in the 3D View applied to your object, is that, having the texture in the Texture panel, or the Texture Paint slot, doesn't mean that the texture is applied to your material.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a little misunderstanding.

At point 1, you are talking about a texture. But at point 2, you are in the material panel. So you wont find your texture here.

An object is rendered with one (or more) material(s). And a material may use an image to render.

As you are using Cycles rendering :

1. Go to the material tab
2. Open the "surface" section
3. Click on the little dot near the color
4. Choose "Image texture"
5. Choose or open your image here (you'll have to choose your image by the image's name, not the texture's name : Cycles uses images directly)

[image]
[image]
[image]