# Why does my object lose color when the slot is changed?

Tags: texturing, color

I have modeled this. When I add another slot in order to make my man more realistic, it loses color and becomes like a normal object.

[image: Image with colored slot]

And my man with new slot added,

[image: Image with new slot]

Please help so that my object stays in first slot color and uses second slot.

Comment: What do you mean by slot? Could you provide more details?

Comment: You need to add the texture to your object's material, check this link see if it helps: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56329/texture-uv-map-is-not-applied-to-the-object-while-im-following-the-projection-p?noredirect=1#comment96154_56329

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't exactly "lose color". Paint slots are handled as layers, so if you add a new slot to your model it "spraypaints" the model with whatever colors you have in that slot. Since in your case there are no colors (or a texture, to be more precise) the model appears to have no color at all.